# How do I quarantine the Jungle from the evil biomes pre hardmode (entering hardmode)?

Tags: terraria

I'm in a Medium, Classic, Crimson World. I have the jungle biome on the left side of the world near the ocean whilst the crimson biome is on the right side near the other ocean.

I've been researching ways on containing the evil biomes and from what I've read, the best way is to dig two hellevators (3 block wide with uncorruptable blocks on either side of the hellevators) on either side of the Jungle.

My question is, do I need to put a hellevator on the left side of the Jungle even though the crimson biome is on the right?